# Cannot find USB external HDD /dev/sda

Tags: usb, partitioning, external-hard-drive, ubuntu-server, embedded-linux

I am running as usual my orange pi one plus H6 ALL WINNER with ubuntu server and cannot find my exFat HDD on it, it detects the usb but not /dev/sda and cannot mount or access it, yes I tried with ntfs

This is what I see (image below), should be 232 GB HDD connected via USB, sata is not an option

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYoBZ.jpg)

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the file system ExFAT was developed by Microsoft and by law it is forbidden to embed support for ExFAT by default into open source operating systems, which is Ubuntu.

```
sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse exfat-utils
```

If there are problems with the installation, then run the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install fuse fuse-exfat exfat-utils
```

Then we insert a USB drive or a memory card and execute the following commands:

```
sudo mkdir /media/exfat
sudo mount -t exfat /dev/sda1 /media/exfat
```

But instead of /dev/sda1 you must enter your values.
After:

```
sudo umount /media/exfat
```

Comment: Does not work, can't find fuse-exfat and ERROR: failed to open 'dev/sda1: No such file or directory

Comment: Error. The package is called `exfat-fuse` and it is in the repositories ubuntu. what version of ubuntu?